# Trying to do more than one page slider with css and js

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

I want that when I call the page 2 then this makes the slider effect and show the div. Adding a width of 200% or something. But I need some help. Does anyone could help me?

http://jsfiddle.net/juxzg6fn/

```
<html>

<head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <style>

        body {
            overflow: hidden; <!-- quitar scroll -->
        }

        .page {
            position: absolute;
            padding: 12px;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .page.left {
            -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
        }

        .page.center {
            -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        }

        .page.right {
            -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
        }

        .page.transition {
            -webkit-transition-duration: .25s;
            transition-duration: .25s;
        }

    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <!-- PAG 1 -->
    <div id="homePage" class="page transition center" style="background-color: #5AAED5">
        <h1>Home Page</h1>
        <a href="javascript:slidePageFrom(page1, 'right');">Page 1</a><br/a>
        <a href="javascript:slidePageFrom(page1, 'right');">Page 2</a>
    </div>

    <!-- PAG 2 -->
    <div id="p1" class="page transition right" style="background-color: #8ca83d">
        <h1>Page 1</h1>
        <a href="javascript:slidePageFrom(homePage, 'left');">Back</a>
    </div>

    <script>

        var homePage = document.getElementById("homePage");
        var page1 = document.getElementById("p1");

        var currentPage = homePage;

        function slidePageFrom(page, from) {
            // Position the page at the starting position of the animation
            page.className = "page " + from;

            // Position the new page and the current page at the ending position of their animation with a transition class indicating the duration of the animation
            page.className ="page transition center";
            currentPage.className = "page transition " + (from === "left" ? "right" : "left");
            currentPage = page;
        }

    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you make your question clear?? i didn't get what you are saying

Comment: you missed page2.see in console page2 is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call page2 by using `<a href="javascript:slidePageFrom(page2, 'right');">Page 2</a>`. You declare `page2` as a variable, but it isn't declared.

You could fix it by adding this line to your JS code.

```
var page2 = document.getElementById("p2");
```

However, for every new page that you add, you'll need to declare a variable. It is easier if you make it dynamic, using the `id` of the pages (which you already use).

You could change your HTML to (please note the single quotes in the anchors around `p1`, `p2` and `homePage`):

```
<!-- PAG 1 -->
<div id="homePage" class="page transition center" style="background-color: #5AAED5">
    <h1>Home Page</h1>
    <a href="javascript:slidePageFrom('p1', 'right');">Page 1</a><br/>
    <a href="javascript:slidePageFrom('p2', 'right');">Page 2</a>
</div>
<!-- PAG 2 -->
<div id="p1" class="page transition right" style="background-color: #8ca83d">
    <h1>Page 1</h1>
    <a href="javascript:slidePageFrom('homePage', 'left');">Back</a>
</div>
<!-- PAG 2 -->
<div id="p2" class="page transition right" style="background-color: #8ca83d">
    <h1>Page 2</h1>
    <a href="javascript:slidePageFrom('homePage', 'left');">Back</a>
</div>
```

And use this corresponding JS code:

```
var currentPage = document.getElementById('homePage');

function slidePageFrom(page, from) {
    // Position the page at the starting position of the animation
    var page = document.getElementById(page);
    page.className = "page " + from;

    // Position the new page and the current page at the ending position of their animation with a transition class indicating the duration of the animation
    page.className = "page transition center";
    currentPage.className = "page transition " + (from === "left" ? "right" : "left");
    currentPage = page;
}
```

You can find a [**working demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/juxzg6fn/2/).

Comment: Really nice, its true with dynamic more easy. Thanks!

Comment: @BlackCode, your welcome! If the answer suits you, please mark it as solution (v-mark on the left of it).

Comment: If I want make the left slider effect it looks weird. How can i fix it? :S

Answer (score 1):

add line:

```
var page2 = document.getElementById("p2");
```

This version of code is better: http://jsfiddle.net/juxzg6fn/1/
Good luck!

Comment: Nice! This is nice way too! Thanks!